# Need help in adding Custom Action to Custom Button!

Tags: 2010, ribbon

I am adding a custom button to SP Ribbon with exactly same functionality as OOTB "Save and Close" button.  I am trying to add it though custom action but other solutions are welcome as well. My problem with custom action is that Command Action is not firing

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction Id="Ribbon.CustomAction2"
                Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
                Title="Custom Ribbon">
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.WikiPageTab.EditAndCheckout.Controls._children">
          <Button Id="Ribbon.CustomAction.Button2"
                  Sequence="30"
                  Alt="$Resources:core,save;"
Command="ECMAScriptComand"
CommandValueId="PageStateGroupSaveAndStop"
Image16by16="/_layouts/$Resources:core,Language;/images/formatmap16x16.png" Image16by16Top="-176" Image16by16Left="-96"
Image32by32="/_layouts/$Resources:core,Language;/images/formatmap32x32.png" Image32by32Top="-320" Image32by32Left="0"
                  LabelText="Workflows"
                  TemplateAlias="o1"
                  />
        </CommandUIDefinition>
      </CommandUIDefinitions>            
      <CommandUIHandlers>
        <CommandUIHandler Command="ECMAScriptComand"                          
                          CommandAction="javascript:HelloWorld()">
        </CommandUIHandler>
      </CommandUIHandlers>
    </CommandUIExtension>
  </CustomAction>
  <CustomAction Id="Ribbon.Library.Actions.NewButton.Script"
    Location="ScriptLink"
    ScriptBlock="
    function HelloWorld()
    {
      alert('Hello, world!');
       var result=CoreInvoke('PageActionClick', this);
       alert(result);
    }" />
  </Elements>
```

Answer (score 1):

can you please refer to these for guidance!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff458385.aspx

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms460194.aspx

I dont understand why your script block that your calling is in a different customAction? as I can see from msdn the customAction surrounds the creation of the button and the javascript CommandAction.

I could be wrong tho :) ...

```
<CommandUIHandlers> 
  <CommandUIHandler 
    Command="ECMAScriptComand"    
    CommandAction="javascript:
     function HelloWorld() 
      { 
        alert('Hello, world!'); 
        var result=CoreInvoke('PageActionClick', this); 
        alert(result); 
      }"/>
</CommandUIHandlers>
```

This is a nice link shows you step by step guide adding a button :)
http://www.a2zmenu.com/Tutorials/SharePoint/How-to-add-ribbon-button-in-SharePoint-list-and-library.aspx